# What is an average Facebook credits dialog CTR?

Tags: callback, payment, facebook-credits, credits

We're running a game on Facebook with approx. 300K MAUs.  However, we've noticed that there are very few credits payments.

So I looked into this and noticed that the CTRs seem really strange.

The CTR on **our game payment dialog** where the user can select a virtual currency package is approx. **46%** (people who select a package and click on "pay").

The CTR on the **FB credits dialog** that opens on top of the game is only approx. **0.3%**.  As this is the last step in the payment process, I would have assumed this CTR is MUCH larger.

Background:  The CTR on the FB credits dialog is calculated from the number of callback calls "payments_get_items" vs. "payments_status_update" with status "placed".

I am trying to figure out whether there is some implementation issue.  However, I went through the implementation guide twice and did not find anything to date.  All test payments have worked so far.

It would be interesting to hear about other game developers' experiences.

Thank you,

Charles McAllister

Comment: Any thoughts on the rate of orders settled being only 0.3%?  THANKS!